# I can't access $auth.user from auth plugin or middleware using nuxtjs and getting api from laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

My goal is that i want to access $auth.user.roles from plugin and middleware to be able to not let this role reach the other role page.

what is expected is that when console.log($auth.user) it gives me the user data (id,...) and when a console.log($auth.loggedIn)it gives me true.

My problem is that i can't access $auth.user from plugin and middleware to chieve that which $auth.user = null and $auth.loggedIn = false while im logged in.

here is my nuxt.config.js:

```
axios: {
baseURL: env.parsed.API_URL || 'http://localhost:3000/api',
debug:true},

auth: {
  strategies: {
    local: {
      endpoints: {
        login: {
          url: '/auth/signin',
          method: 'post',
          propertyName: 'data.token'
      },
      user: {
        url: '/auth/me',
        method: 'get',
        propertyName: 'data'
        },
        logout: {
        url: '/auth/signout',
        method: 'post'
        },  
        tokenRequired: true,
        tokenType: 'bearer',
        globalToken: true,
        autoFetchUser: true
      },
    },
  },

  redirect:false,

  plugins: [ '~/plugins/roles.js' ]
```

},

here is my plugins/roles.js :

```
export default function ({app}) {
 const username = app.$auth.user
 if (!app.$auth.loggedIn) {
       
return console.log(username ,'roles plugin ', app.$auth.loggedIn)
```

}}

here is the res: null roles plugin  false

the same result using this code:

```
export default function ({$auth}) {
 const username = $auth.user
 if (!app.$auth.loggedIn) {
       
return console.log(username ,'roles plugin', $auth.loggedIn)
```

}}

Ps:when i use $auth.user in my vue pages it gives me the whole user data (thats wonderfull)

I searched about this problem so i found common answers like :
*Change the user propertyName to false.

*reinstall node_modules.

but same result

Thank you every one <3

Comment: Did you fixed this issue